# I require to change the background of the selected cell in the GridDataControl different from the given VisualStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

As the subject depicts, I am using Syncfusion GridDataControl in my application, to which i have set VisualStyle="DefaultOffice2007Silver" and ShowFilterBar="True".

My application is based on c# .net, wpf concepts.

Now when i click on cell in Grid control or in the filter bar, the selected cell shows the same blue colour as it is when i select a row. My requirement is to change the selected cell to some light visible colour (probably white) so the user can easily identify the cell selected, without changing the visual style.

Intially we were using the version 8.403 dll which had the same behaviour what i required but we have now upgraded to 10.104 dll's, and hence assuming the change in behaviour.

Request to kindly answer the query asap as it is bit urgent.

Thanks,
Manali

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the selection and Current cell background using StyleManager.

```
<syncfusion:GridDataControl x:Name="datagrid"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding GDCSource}"
                            ShowFilterBar="True"
                            VisualStyle="Office14Blue">
    <syncfusion:GridDataControl.StyleManager>
        <syncfusion:GridDataStyleManager>
            <syncfusion:GridDataStyleManager.RowAppearence>
                <syncfusion:RowAppearence CurrentCellSelectionBackground="Green" CurrentCellSelectionForeground="White" 
                                            HighlightSelectionBackground="AliceBlue" HighlightSelectionForeground="Black"/>
            </syncfusion:GridDataStyleManager.RowAppearence>
        </syncfusion:GridDataStyleManager>
    </syncfusion:GridDataControl.StyleManager>
</syncfusion:GridDataControl>
```

The background of filter bar in edit mode is customized through customer cell renderer in the below sample,
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/95320/SyncGDC_948121498908578.zip

Regards,
Sivakumar